# Sound synchronization error using DirectSound

Tags: c, winapi, directsound

I'm using directsound to play a sine wave. The idea is simple : I have an application running at 30fps, and I create a buffer worth of 1/30sec sound each frame, to be played in the next frame.

The way I'm doing it :
I first get the dsound play cursor, and compute the offset and the bytes to write out of it.

```
static void win32_update_soundbuffer(SoundBuffer *source, WIN32SOUNDBUFFER *output) {
free(source->data);


uint32_t play_cursor;
uint32_t write_cursor;
output->handle->GetCurrentPosition((LPDWORD)&play_cursor, (LPDWORD)&write_cursor);

static uint32_t last_play_cursor = -1;
bool play_cursor_moved = last_play_cursor == play_cursor ? false : true;

output->offset = (output->sample_index * output->sample_size) % output->buffer_size;

uint32_t bytes_to_write = 0;
if (output->offset == play_cursor) {
    if (play_cursor_moved) {
        bytes_to_write = output->buffer_size;
    }
}
else if (output->offset < play_cursor) { bytes_to_write = play_cursor - output->offset; }
else if (output->offset > play_cursor) { bytes_to_write = output->buffer_size - (output->offset - play_cursor); }

last_play_cursor = play_cursor;

source->sample_count = bytes_to_write / output->sample_size;
source->data = (uint16_t *)malloc(bytes_to_write);  //TODO: maybe we don't want to use malloc
}
```

Then I lock the buffer and write the sine wave into it.

```
static void win32_fill_soundbuffer(SoundBuffer *source, WIN32SOUNDBUFFER *output) {

//get the buffer location to write sounds to
output->handle->Lock(output->offset, source->sample_count * output->sample_size, &output->region1, &output->region1_size,
    &output->region2, &output->region2_size, NULL);

uint16_t *source_sample = source->data;
uint16_t *out_sample = (uint16_t *)output->region1;
uint32_t sample_count1 = output->region1_size / output->sample_size;
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sample_count1; i++) {
    *out_sample++ = *source_sample++;
    *out_sample++ = *source_sample++;
    output->sample_index++;
}

out_sample = (uint16_t *)output->region2;
uint32_t sample_count2 = output->region2_size / output->sample_size;
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sample_count2; i++) {
    *out_sample++ = *source_sample++;
    *out_sample++ = *source_sample++;
    output->sample_index++;
}

output->handle->Unlock(output->region1, output->region1_size, output->region2, output->region2_size);
}
```

(the source buffer is something I first send to the "user" to be filled with the sine wave, and then retrieve to fill the real sound buffer. I'm doing it because the project is multi-platform).

The implementation look like that :

```
WIN32SOUNDBUFFER win_soundbuffer = ...
SoundBuffer soundbuffer = ...

while(running) {
    win32_update_soundbuffer(&soundbuffer, &win_soundbuffer);
    user_process_sound(&soundbuffer);
    win32_fill_soundbuffer(&soundbuffer, &win_soundbuffer);
    win_soundbuffer.handle->Play(NULL, NULL, DSBPLAY_LOOPING);
}
```

The errors I'm experiencing : it does only work for some buffer size (1s to 1/8s, no problem. 1/9s is scratching a lot. 1/10s, 1/20s are ok too.) The weirder thing is that it also for 1/40s, which should be impossible since the buffer isn't large enough to last for a frame.
When debugging, I can see that the play cursor isn't moving fast enough, and sometimes it stay at the same place for a few frames, which could be the reason for the scratching.
Does anyone know how to solve that ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Make your DSound buffer several seconds long.  DSound just wasn't meant for micro-sized buffers.

Comment: It's also emulated on all modern versions of Windows which is why it's deprecated. If you want todo something like this, consider using WASAPI directly